# A very questionable driver

Tags: riddle

> I start on red,
>
> I stop on green;
>
> Don't care about yellow,
>
> if ever seen.

Who or what am I?

Answer (score 30):

> A golfer

Explanation:

> You start on the red tees and finish on the green. You rarely see yellow because golf courses are well taken care of and don't normally have yellow grass.

Comment: And that would also explain the "driver" in the title too.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann Agreed, the title seems relevant and this answer accounts for it well. Nice and creative solution!

Comment: I don't think all tees are red though.

Comment: I agree, see here about tee colors https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teeing_ground. Neverthless, +1 for great thinking and it does fit in albeit with a bit of a squish :-)

Comment: Not all tees are red, but that is one of their standard colors. And it fits with the title.

Answer (score 16):

Could be:

> Battery charging
>  though some chargers use yellow instead of red ;)

Comment: That's a creative and good answer too! +1!

Comment: Apple products use yellow for Low Power Mode.

Answer (score 10):

> Pedestrian

Explanation:

> At a pedestrian crossing, the pedestrian starts when it's red for the cars, stops when it's green for the cars, and (the dodgy part of the explanation) doesn't care about yellow as most cars stop when it's yellow?

Comment: That's good creative thinking! I like it...!

Comment: I rather think they wouldn't care about yellow because a lot of cars *don't* stop, meaning it's not safe and they can't do anything. They have to wait for red.

Comment: No, pedestrians go when the lights facing them are green, same as cars.  They stop when the lights perpendicular are red, same as cars.

Comment: You misread: **for the cars** is the key part in my explanation.

Comment: No, I didn't misread.  It's green for the cars also.  It's only red for the cars moving perpendicular.  That's true whether you're in a car or a pedestrian.  So your answer could just as well be "drivers", which would make this a terribly uninteresting riddle.

Answer (score 5):

Thinking outside the box:

> An entrepreneur.

I start on red,

> An entrepreneur starts in the red to invest into a venture.

I stop on green;

> When the venture makes a profit or when it is bought out, the entrepreneur makes his "green" and (often) moves on to something else.

Don't care about yellow,

> An entrepreneur doesn't care about yellow.

if ever seen.

> If the "green" is ever seen. Often an entrepreneur will fail.

Comment: What does "yellow" represent in the context of entrepreneurs?

Answer (score 3):

> You are the Monopoly car.

I start on red,

> The car can start on one of the red properties (Kentucky Ave, Indiana Ave, Illinois Ave).

I stop on green;

> When rolling and moving from the red properties, often a player will land on one of the green properties (Pacific Ave, North Carolina Ave, Pennsylvania Ave).

Don't care about yellow,

if ever seen.

> If the player gets a roll that will take them from red to green, they must pass the yellow properties (Atlantic Ave, Ventor Ave, Marvin Gardens). In Monopoly, a player can only interact with the properties they land on, so in this case the player wouldn't care about the yellow properties because they are just passing by and don't get to see and purchase them.

[Image for reference](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81oC5pYhh2L._SL1500_.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

> Cross traffic.

Explanation:

> When my light turns red, they start moving.   When my light turns green, they have stopped.  They don't seem to care about my light when it turns yellow -- as they really don't ever see it (unless turning).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, but not likely, you are a...

> Javelin Thrower?

You start on the red...

> clay. Most places (not sure what the official term is) use red clay for javelin throwers. As seen here: [image: Javelin Thrower on Red Clay]

You stop on the green...

> While technically, you stop before the green grass, javelin throwers must stop before it otherwise it is a rules violation.

You don't care about the yellow, if ever seen

> Yellow is only sometimes seen on the javelin itself or the uniform. It is sometimes seen on the track as well and may be used as a marker. Either way, it won't be too important, and is rarely seen.

Well, I tried :)

Answer (score 2):

You're

> the winter cold. You start when leaves are red, you stop when leaves are green.

Comment: What about yellow?

Answer (score 2):

> The brake pedal of a car. You engage it when the light turns red, disengage when it turns green, and hit the gas when it turns yellow!

Comment: Best answer to this question. Wish I had more than one upvote.

Answer (score -1):

One possibility:

> A perfect programmer using Eclipse

Because...

> Doesn't stop on red errors because he knows what he is doing,
>  Always reads the green comments,
>  Doesn't care about yellow because he rarely gets a warning, but if he does, he knows how to fix it without even reading.

Another possibility:

> A scared guy who forgot it was St. Patrick's Day

Because...

> He runs when he sees blood (from pinches)
>  He stops when he sees people are wearing green
>  Yellow shirts aren't worth his time.

Answer (score -2):

An anti-golfer cyclist on his/her/its way to the putting green.

Explanation:

**I start on red:**

> Cyclists are always go straight through red lights and start life as a red socialist, one example of this is the fact that they refuse to just work hard like normal people and get a car.

**I stop on green:**

> Trivial, stopping when they get on the putting green, destroying the surface with their tyres and frightening the animals with their Lycra clad bodies.

**Don't care about yellow, if ever seen:**

> Don't care about the fact that they are perceived as yellow-bellies by others, given that they are too cowardly to cycle on busy roads junctions and instead ride on foot paths, which results in frightened dogs and the scaring of the elderly with their angry, sweaty, smelly, Lycra covered bodies.

.

> Clearly satirical.

Comment: It would be nice if you added some justification to your answer.

Comment: Could you explain why you think this is the answer? Answers without explanation are usually deleted.

Comment: Enjoy my explanation, clear, concise and perfect in every way!

Comment: This seems to make overreaching assumptions about cyclists. Are you trolling?

Comment: Please comment your answer. No one likes a spoiled answer :( You can use `>!` to use spoilers. Even if it satirical, who knows? Either way, it's just common practice.